# Anybody also noticed that Windows 11 multithreaded font usage causes a heap corruption in GDI?

Tags: multithreading, crash, gdi

we have multiple printing applications that draw text into (an enhmetafile) GDI. When these painting actions (in short something like CreateFont(), SelectFont(), DrawText(), GetObject(), ... DeselectFont(), DeleteFont()) are done in threads, the application crashes very soon in DeleteObject() of a font handle. If the threads are synchronized, it does not happen. Under Windows 10 there's is no problem at all.

Reproduction by some simple code is not trivial, and our code is a little complex querying the LOGFONT, querying current object, ... to lay out the page to paint into (including wordbreak etc), and a simple multithreaded sample does not show this behaviour. It must be an unfortunate combination of the font APIs (or a combination with other GDI object APIs).

Trace of the crash is always in the same place, a corrupted heap caused by the DeleteObject API:

```
    ntdll.dll!_RtlReportCriticalFailure@12()    Unknown
    ntdll.dll!_RtlpReportHeapFailure@4()    Unknown
    ntdll.dll!_RtlpHpHeapHandleError@12()   Unknown
    ntdll.dll!_RtlpLogHeapFailure@24()  Unknown
    ntdll.dll!_RtlpFreeHeapInternal@20()    Unknown
    ntdll.dll!RtlFreeHeap() Unknown
    gdi32full.dll!_vFreeCFONTCrit@4()   Unknown
    gdi32full.dll!_vDeleteLOCALFONT@4() Unknown
    gdi32.dll!_InternalDeleteObject@4() Unknown
    gdi32.dll!_DeleteObject@4() Unknown
```

I do write it here in the hope of finding someone who has the same problem - or to be found by someone looking for others (like me here) ;)

Comment: Facing the same issue, in the same context but within Uniscribe ScriptStringOut function which internally frees some object using DeleteObject and never returns. Did you find a real solution?

Answer (score 2):

OK, the culprit for **our** case of printing in a metafile DC has been found: the APIs `GetTextExtentPoint()` and its alias `GetTextExtentPoint32()` are not threadsafe in Windows 11 and do corrupt the GDI heap if GDI text operations are used by multiple threads.

**More findings:**

DC is a metafile DC:

- heap becomes corrupted if `GetTextExtentPoint()´ is being used
- everything works without this API

DC is a Window DC:

- the code always hangs in an endless loop in `ExtTextOut()` or `GetTextExtentPoint()` (if opted in) in the application's painting loop. **BTW: Even in Windows 10**...! Not a deadlock, but full processor load (one at least one of the CPUs, so there's some kind of synchronization)

The code is attached, you may play around with the macros `SHOW_ERROR` and `USE_METAFILE`...:

```
#include "stdafx.h"

#include <windows.h>
#include <windowsx.h>
#include <process.h>
#include <assert.h>

#define SHOW_ERROR      1
#define USE_METAFILE    0

#define sizeofTSTR(b) (sizeof(b)/sizeof(TCHAR))

const int   THREADCOUNT = 20;

struct scThreadData
    {
    public:
        volatile LONG*                  _pnFinished;
        TCHAR                           _szFilename[MAX_PATH];
        DWORD                           _dwFileSize;
    };

void _cdecl g_ThreadFunction(void* pParams)
{
    scThreadData* pThreadData = reinterpret_cast<scThreadData*>(pParams);
    PRINTDLG    pd = {0};
    HDC         hDC = NULL;

    ::Sleep(rand() % 1000);

    printf("start %d\n", ::GetCurrentThreadId());

#if USE_METAFILE
    pd.lStructSize = sizeof(pd);
    pd.Flags = PD_RETURNDC | PD_RETURNDEFAULT;
    ::PrintDlg(&pd);

    RECT    rcPage = {0,0,10000,10000};
    
    hDC = ::CreateEnhMetaFile(pd.hDC, pThreadData->_szFilename, &rcPage, _T("Hallo"));
#else
    hDC = ::GetDC(NULL);
#endif

    for (int i = 0; i < 20000; ++i)
        {
        HFONT   newFont = ::CreateFont(-100, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, DEFAULT_CHARSET, OUT_TT_PRECIS, CLIP_DEFAULT_PRECIS, ANTIALIASED_QUALITY, 0, L"Arial");
        HFONT   oldFont = SelectFont(hDC, newFont);

        ::ExtTextOut(hDC, 0, 0, 0, NULL, _T("x"), 1, NULL);

    #if SHOW_ERROR
        SIZE        sz = {};
        ::GetTextExtentPoint(hDC, L"Hallo", 5, &sz); // <<-- causes GDI heap to be corrupted
    #endif

        SelectFont(hDC, oldFont);
        ::DeleteFont(newFont);
        }

#if USE_METAFILE
    ::DeleteEnhMetaFile(::CloseEnhMetaFile(hDC));
    ::DeleteDC(pd.hDC);
#else
    ::DeleteDC(hDC);
#endif

    ::DeleteFile(pThreadData->_szFilename);

    printf("end %d\n", ::GetCurrentThreadId());

    // done
    ::InterlockedIncrement(pThreadData->_pnFinished);
}


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    volatile LONG   nFinished(0);
    scThreadData    TD[THREADCOUNT];
    TCHAR           szUserName[30];
    TCHAR           szComputerName[30];
    DWORD           dwLen;

    dwLen = sizeofTSTR(szUserName);
    ::GetUserName(szUserName,&dwLen);
    dwLen = sizeofTSTR(szComputerName);
    ::GetComputerName(szComputerName,&dwLen);

    for (int nThread = 0; nThread < THREADCOUNT; ++nThread)
        {
        TD[nThread]._pnFinished = &nFinished;
        _stprintf_s(TD[nThread]._szFilename,MAX_PATH,_T("test-%s-%d.emf"),szUserName,nThread);
        _beginthread(g_ThreadFunction,10000,(void*)&TD[nThread]);
        ::Sleep(200);
        }
    Sleep(1000);

    while (nFinished < THREADCOUNT)
        {
        ::Sleep(100);
        }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: OK, but [this MSDN article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/multiple-threads-and-gdi-objects) seems to suggest that GDI APIs were never thread-safe to begin with. Without really thinking about it I would have generally assumed GDI functions are not thread-safe, unless explicitly specified in the documentation. But nice to see this updated anyway.

Comment: Well this is not a threadsafeness problem as GDI objects can be used in any thread, but not (safely) crossthreaded. Which is not what I was doing, the objects are strictly used in their own thread.